# Difference between Spark RDD's take(1) and first()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I used to think that `rdd.take(1)` and `rdd.first()` are exactly the same. However I began to wonder if this is really true after my colleague pointed me to [Spark's officiation documentation on RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD):

> **first()**: Return the first element in this RDD.
>
> **take(num)**: Take the first num elements of the RDD.
>   It works by first scanning one partition, and use the results from that partition to estimate the number of additional partitions needed to satisfy the limit.

My questions are:

1. Is the underlying implementation of `first()` the same as `take(1)`?
2. Suppose `rdd1` and `rdd2` are constructed from the same csv, can I safely assume that `rdd1.take(1)` and `rdd2.first()` will **always** return the same result, i.e., the first row of the csv? What if `rdd1` and `rdd2` are partitioned differently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Infact `first` is implemented in terms of `take`.

Following is taken from spark's source of [RDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala). `first` calls `take(1)` and returns the first element if found.

```
  def first(): T = withScope {
    take(1) match {
      case Array(t) => t
      case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty collection")
    }
  }
```

`take(num)` tries to take num elements from starting from RDD's 0th partition (if you consider 0 based indexes). So the behavior of take(1) and first will be identical.

Even the [spark programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) confirms this.

About your second question: it depends what you mean when you say partitioned differently. If you are calling `sc.textFile("/path/to/file")` with or without numPartitions, it wouldn't matter because 0th partition will always be 0th partition. So Yes, you can assume that they will have the same first element.

EDIT: Partitions in RDD are ordered, the physical first line in your CSV will end up in the 0th partition on RDD. And `take(1)` and `first` both will return that first row of 0th partition.

Comment: Agree with **Praveen Shukla** answer +1 . adding pointer

@Ida : Please look at how RDD.scala was designed here..

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala

Comment: Thanks @RamPrasadG. I have added link to RDD.scala in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

No both are not same.

`rdd.first()` will Return the first element in this RDD
while `rdd.take(1)` will return an array that will have first element only.

1. Is the underlying implementation of first() the same as take(1)?

Ans : In terms of implementation `first()` calls `take(1)` internally and returns first and only element of the array returned by `take(1)`. Taken from `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` class

```
  /**
   * Return the first element in this RDD.
   */
  def first(): T = withScope {
    take(1) match {
      case Array(t) => t
      case _ => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty collection")
    }
  }
```

2. Suppose rdd1 and rdd2 are constructed from the same csv, can I safely assume that `rdd1.take(1)` and `rdd2.first()` will always return the same result, i.e., the first row of the csv? What if rdd1 and rdd2 are partitioned differently?

Ans : Yes you can assume, partitioning do not change the order in which input was read.

Answer (score 0):

So, its seems that both are same, but we do have differences.

1.When we read data from the file, it is by default a RDD, and a RDD have both `first()` and `take()` attributes.
2.The `first()` attribute returns a row type object while `take()` returns a list type.

But
As soon as we converts our RDD to DataFrame using `.toDF()`, we don't have the `first()` attribute on that DF.

Hope it may clear the concepts further.

[See the image for more clearity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVtHq.png)